# Why does this happen in linear transformation?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

I'm learning linear algebra here from online MOOC's and have just can't understand this. When we want to say rotate a vector by some angle we just multiply it by a transformation matrix to get the resultant vector. Now why do we multiply a vector as viewed from the transformed basis by the same transformation matrix to get the vector as viewed from the normal basis vectors ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you clarify your question, or at least, provide an example of the phenomenon that you want explained?

Comment: @TheoBendit Alright, say I have to rotate [1 0] and [0 1] by 45 degrees anticlockwise i just multiply them by a transformation matrix to get the new basis vectors. Now say we have a new vector as viewed in the reference frame of the new basis vectors. Why do we again apply the transformation matrix on that vector to get the vector as viewed from our original reference frame(the one with basis vectors [1 0] and [0 1]) ?

Comment: I meant apply the transformation matrix by multiply above.

Comment: So, you're multiplying $R=\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\\-1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ to get a transformed basis $B$. When you say "a new vector as viewed in the reference frame of the new basis vectors", are you referring to $[v]_B$, the coordinate vector with respect to $B$, for some new vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^2$? If so, then I guess you'd like to know why $R[v]_B$ produces $v$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, Exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't just hold for rotations; any invertible matrix will work.

Let $M$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix, and $S = (e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ be the standard basis. Then $B = (Me_1, \ldots, Me_n)$ is also a basis, consisting of the columns of $M$.

Consider the map that takes a coordinate vector $[v]_B$ and produces $[v]_S$, i.e. the vector written as usual in standard coordinates. This map is defined as follows:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} \mapsto a_1 Me_1 + \ldots + a_n M e_n = M(a_1 e_1 + \ldots + a_n e_n) = M\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}.$$
So, the map that "undoes" this map, i.e. the one that takes a vector $[v]_S$ to $[v]_B$ must be characterised by multiplication by $M^{-1}$. Therefore,
$$M[v]_B = MM^{-1}[v]_S = [v]_S,$$
as required.

Comment: I again don't get it, I got that B is also a matrix consisting of the columns of M. Shouldn't we multiply [v]b by M^[-1] to get [v]s and not the other way because we we already got the basis vectors by applying M on the standard basis.

Comment: @DeveshLohumi No, not really, as my answer shows. You should remind yourself of what a coordinate vector is. If I have coordinate vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ with respect to basis $(1, 1), (1, -1))$, then this refers to the vector $1(1, 1) + 2(1, -1) = (3, -1)$. That is, to go from coordinate column vector to point in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (or equivalently, standard coordinate vector), you turn the entries in the coordinate vector into coefficients of a linear combination of basis vectors. That's all I'm doing in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, go back to definitions. The coordinates of a vector $\mathbf v$ relative to some basis $\mathcal B = \{\mathbf b_1,\dots,\mathbf b_n\}$ are the coefficients $c_i$ in the unique linear combination $c_1\mathbf b_1+\cdots+c_n\mathbf b_n$ that equals $\mathbf v$. So, when you perform a change of basis from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$, you’re basically solving this equation with $\mathbf v$ and the $\mathbf b_i$ expressed as coordinates relative to the original basis $\mathcal B$, i.e., $$c_1[\mathbf b_1]_{\mathcal B}+\cdots+c_n[\mathbf b_n]_{\mathcal B} = [\mathbf v]_{\mathcal B}$$ or in matrix form $$B[\mathbf v]_{\mathcal B'}=[\mathbf v]_{\mathcal B}.$$ The $\mathbf b_i$ are linearly independent, so $B$ is invertible and the solution to this equation is $B^{-1}[\mathbf v]_{\mathcal B}$.

This is really no different in principle from what you might have learned in basic algebra courses about transforming graphs of functions. Suppose you shift the origin of a Cartesian coordinate system two units right. The coordinates of this new origin in the original coordinate system are obviously $(2,0)$—you’ve *added* $2$ to the $x$-coordinate. However, coordinates in the shifted system are related to the original coordinates via the equation $x'=x-2$. That is, you *subtract* $2$ from a point’s $x$-coordinate to get its $x'$-coordinate—the inverse of what you did to obtain the new origin.

Comment: I wish more texts emphasized what you do in your last paragraph—namely, the contravariant nature of these coordinate changes, which really students first see in simple high school analytic geometry. For one thing, it would prepare everyone for the difference between vectors (which transform contravariantly) and co-vectors (which transform covariantly). I like to use the analogy of dimensional changes, too: if you double the size of the measuring stick, you halve the value of the measurement, etc.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I’ll have to use that measuring stick image in the future—it’s concrete and simple to grasp. I often add scaling to this screed since that reinforces the connection to linear transformations, but left it out this time for brevity.